# I Need to Average mm:ss.000

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a data of time results that I need to average but I cannot get around it in Excel 2007.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
1:08.225
1:08.281
1:13.285
1:13.291
1:13.614
1:13.658
1:15.175
1:15.906
1:20.656
1:27.239
1:31.923
1:50.859
1=minutes, 08=seconds and 225=milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your data into cells A1:A12 in Excel 2007 and entered the formula `=AVERAGE(A1:A12)` into `A13`. Next if you apply the custom number format `mm:ss.000` you will see the thousandths of milliseconds.

Comment: I included use of the `AVERAGE` function in my answer. I'm not sure what else you are asking?

Comment: What are you using? Im using Excel 2007... It doesn't seem to work like your saying...

Comment: Excel 2007 SP2 - I just cut and paste your sample data above and reordered to exclude the blank rows (otherwise you would be dividing by 24 not 12 for the range).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Average function on these values and assign the cell the format mm:ss.000 (Excel does the required conversions)

Comment: I did this but I keep on getting #DIV/0!

Comment: check the range of cells that you are averaging